# Loading OBJ model with Three.js

Tags: three.js

i am new to three.js.tried bellow code for import my .obj in three.js.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( );
                loader.load( "models/poly.obj", function ( object )            
                {
                      scene.add( object );
                });
```

but it give me error..

TypeError: THREE.BufferAttribute is not a constructor
...ergeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array...
i am not able to understand where i going to do mistake.
Plz help me.

Thank you

Comment: can you load poly.obj to other .obj viewers?

Comment: thank you for reply..its syntex error..var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader;

Comment: As you can see in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html the call to `THREE.OBJLoader()` is valid. `THREE.ObjectLoader` is a totally different call.